# Why I cannot receive email by using AWS SES in . Net

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I used the sample from AWS webpage to check whether I can receive an email by using AWS SES SDK.

It shows the email has been sent successfully, but no email received when I check my email account.

The sender's email has been verified.

The code is the same as the given simple. Only the email addresses are different.

When I paste the code in VS 2017, an error is thrown for Client.SendEmail().

I modified it as recommending to Client.SendEmailAsync(). Have no idea where the issue cloud be.

```
using Amazon;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;

namespace AmazonSESSample 
{
    class Program
    {

        static readonly string senderAddress = "*****";

        static readonly string receiverAddress = "******";


        static readonly string configSet = "ConfigSet";


        static readonly string subject = "Amazon SES test (AWS SDK for .NET)";


        static readonly string textBody = "Amazon SES Test (.NET)\r\n" 
                                        + "This email was sent through Amazon SES "
                                        + "using the AWS SDK for .NET.";


        static readonly string htmlBody = @"<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Amazon SES Test (AWS SDK for .NET)</h1>
  <p>This email was sent with
    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses/'>Amazon SES</a> using the
    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/'>
      AWS SDK for .NET</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

          using (
var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) 
            {
                var sendRequest = new SendEmailRequest
                {
                    Source = senderAddress,
                    Destination = new Destination
                    {
                        ToAddresses =
                        new List<string> { receiverAddress }
                    },
                    Message = new Message
                    {
                        Subject = new Content(subject),
                        Body = new Body
                        {
                            Html = new Content
                            {
                                Charset = "UTF-8",
                                Data = htmlBody
                            },
                            Text = new Content
                            {
                                Charset = "UTF-8",
                                Data = textBody
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    ConfigurationSetName = configSet
                };
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending email using Amazon SES...");
                    var response = client.SendEmailAsync(sendRequest);
                    Console.WriteLine("The email was sent successfully.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);

                }
            }

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `var response = client.SendEmailAsync(sendRequest).Result;` (adding "Async" changes the return type of the method)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @HansKesting Avoid using .Result and use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead, because .Result will not unwrap the exception. https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Brandon-Minnick-asyncawait-best-practices/?WT.mc_id=none-github-bramin

Answer (score 3):

## Bug

The `Main` method is ending before the email is sent because we are not waiting for `Task response` to finish.

`SendEmailAsync` returns a `Task`, meaning these two lines of code are identical:

1. `var response = client.SendEmailAsync(sendRequest);`
2. `Task response = client.SendEmailAsync(sendRequest);`

## Solutions

If you have the latest version of Visual Studio installed and have C#7.1 enabled, you can take advantage of `async Task Main` and use the `await` keyword which will tell the code to run `SendEmailAsync` on a different thread and `Main` won't end until `SendEmail` has completed.

If you are using an older version of Visual Studio, you can add `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, which will also ensure `Main` won't end until `SendEmail` has completed, but `SendEmailAsync` will lock the current thread.

### C#7.1 and Above (Preferred)

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

    using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) 
    {
        var sendRequest = new SendEmailRequest
        {
            Source = senderAddress,
            Destination = new Destination
            {
                ToAddresses =
                new List<string> { receiverAddress }
            },
            Message = new Message
            {
                Subject = new Content(subject),
                Body = new Body
                {
                    Html = new Content
                    {
                        Charset = "UTF-8",
                        Data = htmlBody
                    },
                    Text = new Content
                    {
                        Charset = "UTF-8",
                        Data = textBody
                    }
                }
            },

            ConfigurationSetName = configSet
        };
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending email using Amazon SES...");
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(sendRequest);
            Console.WriteLine("The email was sent successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
            Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);

        }
    }

    Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

### C#7.0 and below

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1)) 
    {
        var sendRequest = new SendEmailRequest
        {
            Source = senderAddress,
            Destination = new Destination
            {
                ToAddresses =
                new List<string> { receiverAddress }
            },
            Message = new Message
            {
                Subject = new Content(subject),
                Body = new Body
                {
                    Html = new Content
                    {
                        Charset = "UTF-8",
                        Data = htmlBody
                    },
                    Text = new Content
                    {
                        Charset = "UTF-8",
                        Data = textBody
                    }
                }
            },

            ConfigurationSetName = configSet
        };
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending email using Amazon SES...");
            var response = client.SendEmailAsync(sendRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine("The email was sent successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
            Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);

        }
    }

    Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```